# How to optimize AndroidView composable with a lazy list layout in compose

Tags: android, exoplayer, pager, lazycolumn, jetpack-compose-accompanist

I have got two problems, scrolling through `LazyColumn` or `VerticalPager` with `AndroidView` filling the whole screen as a child item lags the screen and the scrolling behavior for a couple of milliseconds as well as overlapping items. In my code the `AndroidView` creates `PlayerView`, I also tried to replace `PlayerView` with a `TextView` to check maybe the problem is with `PlayerView` itself. I can't seem to find the root of the problem exactly, maybe with the `AndroidView` or the implementation of the `VerticalPager` itself, or maybe because it fills the whole screen?

**ViewScreen**

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalPagerApi::class)
@Composable
fun VideoScreen() {
    val pagerState = rememberPagerState()
    Box {
        VerticalPager(
            count = videos.size,
            state = pagerState,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            itemSpacing = 10.dp
        ) { index ->

            VideoPlayer(
                vid = videos[index],
                shouldPlay = false
            )
        }
    }
}
```

**VideoPlayer**

```
@Composable
fun VideoPlayer(
    vid: Video,
    shouldPlay: Boolean
) {
    val exoPlayer = rememberExoPlayerWithLifecycle(vid.url)
    val playerView = rememberPlayerView(exoPlayer)

        AndroidView(
            factory = { playerView },
            modifier = Modifier,
            update = {
                exoPlayer.playWhenReady = shouldPlay
            }
        )

    DisposableEffect(key1 = true) {
        onDispose {
            exoPlayer.release()
        }
    }
}
```

**rememberExoPlayerWithLifecycle**

```
@Composable
fun rememberExoPlayerWithLifecycle(
    url: String
): ExoPlayer {

    val context = LocalContext.current
    val exoPlayer = remember(url) {
        ExoPlayer.Builder(context).build().apply {
            videoScalingMode = C.VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT
            repeatMode = Player.REPEAT_MODE_ONE
            setHandleAudioBecomingNoisy(true)
            val defaultDataSource = DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory()
            val source = ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(defaultDataSource)
                .createMediaSource(MediaItem.fromUri(url))
            setMediaSource(source)
            prepare()
        }
    }
    var appInBackground by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }
    val lifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current
    DisposableEffect(key1 = lifecycleOwner, appInBackground) {
        val lifecycleObserver = getExoPlayerLifecycleObserver(exoPlayer, appInBackground) {
            appInBackground = it
        }
        lifecycleOwner.lifecycle.addObserver(lifecycleObserver)
        onDispose {
            lifecycleOwner.lifecycle.removeObserver(lifecycleObserver)
        }
    }
    return exoPlayer
}
```

**rememberPlayerView**

```
@Composable
fun rememberPlayerView(exoPlayer: ExoPlayer): PlayerView {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val playerView = remember {
        PlayerView(context).apply {
            layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, MATCH_PARENT)
            useController = false
            resizeMode = AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_ZOOM
            player = exoPlayer
            setShowBuffering(SHOW_BUFFERING_ALWAYS)
        }
    }
    DisposableEffect(key1 = true) {
        onDispose {
            playerView.player = null
        }
    }
    return playerView
}
```

**build.gradle (Project)**

```
buildscript {
ext {
    compose_version = '1.3.0-beta01'
   }
}
plugins {
    ...
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.10' apply false
}
...
```

**build.gradle (Module)**

```
...
dependencies {
    ...

    //Pager
    implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-pager:0.26.2-beta"

    //Media 3
    def mediaVersion = "1.0.0-beta02"
    implementation "androidx.media3:media3-exoplayer:$mediaVersion"
    implementation "androidx.media3:media3-ui:$mediaVersion"

    ...
}
```

**Overlapping Items**

[image: one]
[image: two]

Comment: I'm in the same situation, did you manage to get a solution for this question. If you did please share. Thanks.

Comment: @KingOfTheJungle Unfortunately not yet. I have issued an issue on https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/241959701 and according to google, they're working on optimizing it. So currently all we have to do is wait.

Comment: hey, did you find solution to this? The ^^ issue has been merged but the rendering is still wrong

Answer (score 0):

Use AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_FIT

Comment: doesn't solve the issue as I have said in the question I replaced the PlayerView with a TextView and still, a performance issue has occurred.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and update verticalpager to 0.25.1 exoplater to 2.18.1 and used a StyledPlayerView instead of PlayerView and it seems to be working.

Comment: I have done the following:


* updated compose to 1.3.0-beta01 and kotlin plugin to 1.7.10
* updated pager library to 0.26.2-beta.
And by the way, I'm using the Media3 library with the latest version 1.0.0-beta02

Comment: Is it working now or are you facing the same issue?

Comment: Nope, still having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using

```
resizeMode = AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_ZOOM
```

replace it with

```
resizeMode = AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_FIT
player.videoScalingMode = C.VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT_WITH_CROPPING
```